# jquery lightbox opening HTML content instead of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightbox, lightbox2

is it possible to open a lightbox window which contains HTML content rather than just an image like in the [demos](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)?

The example listed:

```
<a href="img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption">Image #1</a>
```

Will open the image `image-1.jpg` in a new lightbox window.

Is there a way using this plugin to do something like this:

```
<a href="#mycontent" data-lightbox="mycontent">View content</a>

<div id="mycontent">I am some content</div>
```

And then have the div `mycontent` be shown in the lightbox window when clicking the link?

Comment: That plugin seems to only support images. You may need to use another one or make a custom script.

Comment: [fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) is a good alternative that lets you open up content. Or you could use [jQueryUI's dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) and style it to suit your needs

Answer (score 3):

Lightbox supports images only.

There are alternative scripts that allow you to show HTML content.